# Using "input" command in forvalues; Stata acts like I hit break

Tags: loops, input, stata

I am trying to create empty observations for a number of fruits and a number of years. I thought it would be very straightforward, but Stata acts like I hit the "Break" key after the first time it enters the loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
clear all
gen fruit = .
gen year = .

forvalues f = 10001/10400 {
    forvalues y = 2002/2009 {
        input
        `f' `y'
        end
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cute idea, but it is not workable.

1. `end` has a meaning within loops which clashes with its meaning to `input`.
2. If you `input` outside the loops, then it will not understand the loop syntax.

Here is another way to do it:

```
. clear all

. set obs `=400 * 8' 
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 3,200

. egen fruit = seq(), from(10001) to(10400) block(8) 

. egen year = seq(), from(2002) to(2009) 

. l in 1/16, sep(8) 

     +--------------+
     | fruit   year |
     |--------------|
  1. | 10001   2002 |
  2. | 10001   2003 |
  3. | 10001   2004 |
  4. | 10001   2005 |
  5. | 10001   2006 |
  6. | 10001   2007 |
  7. | 10001   2008 |
  8. | 10001   2009 |
     |--------------|
  9. | 10002   2002 |
 10. | 10002   2003 |
 11. | 10002   2004 |
 12. | 10002   2005 |
 13. | 10002   2006 |
 14. | 10002   2007 |
 15. | 10002   2008 |
 16. | 10002   2009 |
     +--------------+
```

You don't quite have empty observations now, but we know what you mean.